# Rails text_area won't load via js if a newline is present

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a comment form that renders the content of the text area via js. This works as long as there is no new line entered in the text area, when there is it doesn't appear but once the page is refreshed the comment appears (though without a new line). It get's commited to the database and the server says the js file has been rendered.

This is my comment.js.erb;

```
$('#comments').append("<div class='comment'><h4><%= @comment.body %></h4></div>");
```

Comment: Take a look at `simple_format`

Answer (score 0):

Adding `escape_javascript` and `html_safe` was the only thing that worked for me, though it still doesn't display newlines properly.

```
$('#comments').append("<div class='comment'><h4><%= escape_javascript(@comment.body).html_safe %></h4></div>");
```